# SnackBar invoked three times in the third screen on single Increment or Decrement, where I'm missing?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc

I have implemented BlocConsumer for listening to the stream, which will trigger the snack bar widget depending on the state event.
*The snack bar is getting triggered three times on a single increment event on the third screen and two times on the second screen. How to make it show once every click on both screens I am using the bloc, flutter_bloc package, any suggestion or direction will be helpful, thank you.*

[image: Gif image fo the issue]

```
class SecondScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SecondScreen({Key? key, required this.title, required this.color})
      : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  final Color color;
  @override
  _SecondScreenState createState() => _SecondScreenState();
}

class _SecondScreenState extends State<SecondScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          widget.title.toString(),
        ),
        backgroundColor: widget.color,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('SECOND PAGE', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4),
            const SizedBox(height: 40.0),
            const Text(
              'You have clicked this many times',
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10.00),
            BlocConsumer<CounterCubit, CounterState>(
              listener: (context, state) {
                // show a snackbar everytime the state changes
                // this block of code is listening to every event triggering in the state
                if (state.wasIncremented == true) {
                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                    const SnackBar(
                      content: Text('Incremented'),
                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
                    ),
                  );
                } else if (state.wasIncremented == false) {
                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                    const SnackBar(
                      content: Text('Decremented'),
                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
                    ),
                  );
                }
              },
              builder: (context, state) {
                return Text(
                  state.counterValue.toString(),
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                );
              },
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                FloatingActionButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    // TO DO
                    BlocProvider.of<CounterCubit>(context).decrement();
                  },
                  child: const Icon(Icons.remove),
                  heroTag: const Text('btn1'),
                ),
                FloatingActionButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      // TO DO
                      BlocProvider.of<CounterCubit>(context).increment();
                    },
                    child: const Icon(Icons.add),
                    heroTag: const Text('btn2')),
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 50.00),
            MaterialButton(
              height: 50.00,
              minWidth: 200.00,
              child: const Text('Navigate to Next Screen'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (_) => BlocProvider<CounterCubit>.value(
                      value: BlocProvider.of<CounterCubit>(context),
                      child: const ThirdScreen(
                          title: 'Third Screen', color: Colors.amberAccent),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
`Cubit state`
// ignore_for_file: unnecessary_this

part of 'counter_cubit.dart';

// @immutable
// abstract class CounterState {}

class CounterState {
  int counterValue;
  bool wasIncremented;

  CounterState({
    required this.counterValue,
    required this.wasIncremented,
  });

  // @override
  // List<Object> get props => [this.counterValue, this.wasIncremented];
}
```

```
`Cubit`
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';

part 'counter_state.dart';

class CounterCubit extends Cubit<CounterState> {
  CounterCubit() : super(CounterState(counterValue: 0, wasIncremented: false));

  void increment() => emit(
      CounterState(counterValue: state.counterValue + 1, wasIncremented: true));
  void decrement() => emit(CounterState(
      counterValue: state.counterValue - 1, wasIncremented: false));
}
```

```
`Bloc is provided here`

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<CounterCubit>(
      create: (BuildContext context) => CounterCubit(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: const HomeScreen(title: 'First Screen', color: Colors.blueAccent),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the BLOC code?

Comment: I have just updated the post.

Comment: I don't think you should user "BlocProvider" under MaterialPageRoute.